# Output report on bluetooth Hid over GATT

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, bluez

I'm waorking on HID over GATT in Bluez , I want to know how the output reports created by hid_output_report goes to userspace.Thanks in advance

Comment: which Bluez are you using? 4.99 or 5.2?